# coroutine Flow : Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

When I am trying to change the Dao to the new `Flow`Api, I am getting the compilation error stating that

```
Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type
    public abstract kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow<java.util.List<com.ezek.ezign.model.ECampaign>> readCampaigns();
```

The Dao is

```
@Dao
interface CampaignDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM campaign ORDER BY timeStamp ASC")
    fun readCampaigns(): Flow<List<ECampaign>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM campaign WHERE id = :campaignId")
    fun readCampaign(campaignId: Int): Flow<ECampaign>
}
```

and the dependencies are

```
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2'

    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.ext.room_version"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.ext.room_version"

//room_version = "2.1.0"
```

I have tried with Both `List` and `ArrayList`, but No luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Do not use both suspend and Flow<> on the same method! Like this

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    suspend fun loadAll(): Flow<Array<User>>
```

Just

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    suspend fun loadAll(): Array<User>
```

OR

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
   fun loadAll(): Flow<Array<User>>
```

Comment: "Do not use both suspend and Flow<> on the same method" - This should be the error message

Comment: No need to use suspend keyword when we return Flow

Comment: @ScottCooper that can't be done, it will make our lives too easy.

Comment: @X09 we are basically getting paid for searching questions at stackoverflow

Comment: above answer is correct but consider changing room_version to at least `2.4.2`

Answer (score 2):

You've left a comment that you're using `2.1.0` as Room version. Please give [this](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/08/08/room-flow.html) a read and you'll find that `2.2.0-alpha2` is required for using `Flow`. Update the version and it should work.

> Room 2.2.0-alpha02 advertised Flow support

Answer (score 0):

I tried the approaches provided in the other answers, namely avoiding `Flow` and `LiveData` in `DAO` that have `suspend` function but I was still getting the error.

In the end, my problem was related to my dependencies. I had multiple room dependencies like:

```
    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt           "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```

When only the last one was required (SEE EDIT):

```
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.5"
```

*EDIT*

Actually, this is not event true. It compiled fine but when I launched the app, I had an error at runtime.

I could make it work by swapping the compiler version:

```
    def room_version = "2.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt           "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
```